Still Unable to peacefully work with Tensorflow with Mac Silicon Chip
I am still struggling to get Tensorflow to work on my Mac M1 Chip.
I have occasionally managed in the past, but when I get a new laptop and try again, it often fails.
Last time it worked I followed the first answer here:Stack Overflow answer.
I used the .yml file therein presented, call it tf.yml
name: tf-metal
channels:
  - apple
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.9  ## specify desired version
  - pip
  - tensorflow-deps

  ## uncomment for use with Jupyter
  ## - ipykernel

  ## PyPI packages
  - pip:
    - tensorflow-macos
    - tensorflow-metal  ## optional, but recommended


installed Miniforge (via homebrew), and followed all the steps mentioned in the post for the "Emulated (osx-64) base"
## create env
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-arm64 mamba env create -n my_tf_env -f tf-metal-arm64.yaml

## activate
mamba activate my_tf_env

## permanently set the subdir
conda config --env --set subdir osx-arm64


and it does create an environment and installs tensorflow.
If I run
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

I get the expected answer
2.16.2

If I try a "smoke test" with the script
cifar = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar.load_data()
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=True,
    weights=None,
    input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
    classes=100,)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)

it fails after a bit, with the error
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:353] CHECK failed: target + size == res: 
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: CHECK failed: target + size == res: 
zsh: abort      python tf_smoke_test.py

I found a similar error mentioned here, but it is well above my paygrade.
The only suggestion in the said thread that makes sense to me is that one should use tensorflow-macos, not the tensorflow package.
Now, if I look at the packages installed in the mamba environment I have created via the .yml file, I find all sorts:
tensorflow                2.16.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-deps           2.10.0                        0    apple
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.37.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-macos          2.16.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metal          1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi


So the questions:

why is tensorflow being installed, nowhere in the .yml file I am using to create the mamba env I see tensorflow mentioned
is this the problem why my little tensorflow "smoke test" script fails?
what is the solution to all of this?
bonus question: why is Miniforge critical? From the point of finding the right tensorflow package for MAC M1, Is it not the same as using Conda and specifying conda-forge as a channel?


Try without   - tensorflow-deps in your yml file

@Flying Teller, oh my, it is training now. I still see both tensorflow and tensorflow-macos have been installed, but the model is training with no error. What is actually in tensorflow-deps? What is going on? Thank you, you Wise One!
